# Applying border in combination with boxing-size

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to decrease a border-top width? I'm using boxing-size so the boxes are aligned. I want it like this:

[image]

But when I apply a border-top to the div there is still a space between te divs but the border doesn't top. 
[image]

Any fix for this?

Comment: Could you put the code in a jsfiddle please? I think it will be more clear to understant, because you're saying the problem is border-top but maybe you have the problem with the first and second div width.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say _"the border doesn't top"_.

Comment: Use `margin` for boxes instead of `padding`.

Comment: @ArnauGuadall I'll get a code online

Comment: @ChristianVarga Meant "stop" my bad.

Answer (score 0):

See according to your image i made this example.

```css
.main-container{
width:998px;
  height:auto;

}

.box{
width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-top:2px solid #b40505;
  float:left;
  background:#fefbdf;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
<div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Border does not give a F* about padding, inside your colums you have to create a new div where you put in the content.

Take a look at my bootply and you'll understand!

[**BOOTPLY BOXES**](http://www.bootply.com/eITNOpbEh3)